# Retrieve mysql data that doesn't contain number

Tags: php, mysql

I need to retrieve a list of words, but don't want any words that contain a number or numbers in them.

The idea is very simple, but I'm not even sure how to try. I have one column of words some of which have numbers in them. I only want to retrieve the ones without numbers.

How would I do this in my SQL query?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: It is very simple, but I'm not even sure how to try. I have one column of words some of which have numbers in them. I only want to retrieve the ones without numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression, either with php's preg_match, or with REGEXP in mysql.

`SELECT list_col FROM list_table WHERE list_col NOT REGEXP '[0-9]'`

Comment: That worked good! Could I also remove a "-"